# Stylesheets do not work in firefox

Tags: css, firefox

i have 2 styles in my code:
like this:

```
<style id="dramatic">
            body{
            font-family:Verdana;
            color: white;
            background-color:black; 
            }
        </style>
        <style id="normal" disabled="true">
            body{
                font-family:Times;
                color:black;
                background-color: white;
            }
        </style>
```

but it does not work in FF! why?

Comment: What behavior are you seeing and what do you expect? Simply declaring that something doesn't work doesn't allow anyone to effectively help you.

Comment: One resource that has helped me in the past is to play around with something using jsfiddle.net

Comment: The `style` tag doesn't have any `id` or `disabled` attribute.

Comment: so many different problems it can be... delete the id-attribute... check if you have a body... check if you have no other styles overwriting it... it works and you "cant see it"... it works but you except something others... and so on

Comment: font attribute works but color attributes do not work.there is a javascript function to enable these styles one to one

Answer (score 2):

Those attributes (id, disabled) don't work for the style tag, or at least I've never come across them before. I did a quick search and I can't find any references to them either.

Comment: You are correct. There are no such attributes for style.

Comment: i think you are right Matt!.. my code is simple code..i defined 2 styles with 1 JavaScript function to enable these styles but just font attribute works and color or background color donot work!..

Comment: see MetalFrog's answer + link. you seem to be missing the fundamentals of css and how its classes work.